# Using $HOME in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I am working on a Qt project and I want the working directories to be dynamically set for the program will be run on different systems.

I have enclosed the code for your reference.

```
QProcess Home;
Home.start("echo",QStringList() << "$HOME");
Home.waitForFinished(-1);
qDebug() << Home.readAllStandardOutput();
```

But the qDebug() prints "$HOME" and not the actual home path. Why does this happen? Is There any other way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you think it should replace `$HOME` with the actual home path?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Because `system("echo $HOME")` does too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::getenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) to retrieve the home path set in the processes environment.

```
#include <cstdlib>

const char *homePath = std::getenv("HOME");
if(homePath != NULL)
{
    QProcess Home;
    Home.start("echo",QStringList() << homePath);
    Home.waitForFinished(-1);
    qDebug() << Home.readAllStandardOutput();
}
```

Comment: You can also use `QDir::homePath()` to get the home path. And `qgetenv` can be used instead of `std::getenv`.

Comment: +1 for `QDir::homePath()`. That works on Windows, too. `$HOME` is POSIX.

Comment: @Riateche, thank you that really helped but now I have another problem. I can access $HOME, but I can't access other user defined environment variables. Would be great if you can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it.

`QStringList QProcess::systemEnvironment () [static]`

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#systemEnvironment

```
 QStringList environment = QProcess::systemEnvironment();
  // environment = {"PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin",
  //                "USER=greg", "HOME=/home/greg"}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[QByteArray qgetenv ( const char * varName )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qgetenv) is the function provided by QT library to fetch any environment variable on all platforms.

getenv() seems to be deprecated on Windows VS2005 onward [more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Especially for home path you should use QDir::homePath()

Comment: thank you,it really helped, but now I want to access userdefined environment variables. qgetenv doesn't give me the answer. Please help me out.